# Pieceable for Android

Tags: android, ios, browser

I have seen Pieceable which is a Website where you can Upload iOS Apps and then try them out directly in the browser. Is something like this also available for Android?

To upload an APK File, embedd some code into a website and be able to try out the App before buying it?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this does not belong here but just that it is answered I'm going to give the answer. I found [AppSurfer](http://www.appsurfer.com) to work very nicely.